# Disable keyboard shortcuts in kiosk mode for the chromium browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debian, webbrowser-control

Is there any way to disable keyboard shortcuts in chromium browser in Debian OS ? After booting the OS i am triggering the chromium browser, and i want to disable keyboard shortcuts like CTRL + N, CTRL + T, CTRL + W etc.

Comment: Is this question about a webbrowser control that uses Chromium? If so, which one? There is Awesomium, CefSharp, Google's Chrome Frame,  and DotNetBrowser. And those are just the .Net ones. There's certainly many more that use the Chromium Embedded Framework.

Comment: I am asking because each one could potentially have it's own API.

Comment: Yes. i am developing for Javascript web app. Am not sure which one to look into? please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am working on kiosk mode in RPi. That's Debian based. There are 2 solutions. First use xmodmap. xmodmap disables input fromkeyboard. This is awesome for you! You can write in some auto-start file comamnds like "xmodmap -e "keycode 115 =". This will disable (i think) left control. With this comamnds you can disable all letters you dont want. But there's one problem. When i was on RPi lite theres no GUI so only one way to access system was by SSH. Not by keyboard and then this is hard for debugging. Second solution is to download https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck this extension. It works perfectly. It just blocks keybpard inputs when chromium (chrome) is active. Just one note: don't edit settings of this app in app's settings but in chrome keyboard shortcuts management. The url is chrome://extensions/shortcuts